# Jasmine plugin for Maven: issue with SNAPSHOT

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, maven, plugins, jasmine

I'm new to Maven and Jasmine, and to start out I try to follow the usage example on [on the github page](http://searls.github.com/jasmine-maven-plugin/usage.html) and this is the first command to begin with:

> mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeRepository=http://searls-maven-repository.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/snapshots -DarchetypeGroupId=com.github.searls -DarchetypeArtifactId=jasmine-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.3.1.0-SNAPSHOT -DgroupId=com.acme -DartifactId=my-jasmine-project -Dversion=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

If you go to [the archtype repository here](http://searls-maven-repository.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/snapshots/com/github/searls/jasmine-archetype/); the latest snapshot is 1.2.0. The command above refers to 1.3.1 in `-DarchetypeVersion=1.3.1.0-SNAPSHOT`.

I get this error:

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (com.github.searls:jasmine-archetype:1.3.1.0-SNAPSHOT)

Is there another repository I should use?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I was able to generate the archetype using this configuration.

```
mvn archetype:generate \
-DarchetypeRepository=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/searls/jasmine-archetype/2.0/ \
-DarchetypeGroupId=com.github.searls \
-DarchetypeArtifactId=jasmine-archetype \
-DarchetypeVersion=2.0 \
-DjasminePluginVersion=2.1 \
-DgroupId=com.test \
-DartifactId=test \
-Dversion=1.0
```